# How to test the performance of the MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

I have tables in MSQL server2008 which are migrated to MySQL server, tables are migrated along with Procedures, functions, constrains using MySQL migration tool (to convert table data) kit and Sql-ways tool (to convert Procedures, functions).

My ,anager asked me to check the migration done it without any errors and also test the performance of  MSSQL table with MySQL table.

Please help me how to solve this problems, let me know migration procedure it self correct/incorrect